# Is it good connect to servlet server from Java, without website?

Tags: java, android, http, client-server

Several days I didn't learned more about Java server development. I can make a small web-server with WebSocket and Servlet, and Hibernate, like a chat or AuthService. But I'm absolute zero in front-end, and just can't use my knowledge. So, when I found how to use my new skill, I realized what I can made Android app instead of website (because I have experience).  For example, I have servlets like

> /auth/signin
>
> /auth/signup

Is it a good idea make `GET` and `POST` query, from Java code, using Retrofit, for example, or not? Given that I dont have a website, only servlet, on

> domain:port/auth/

I just don't know how to organize my architecture. It must be simple client-server, client = android.

Questions: Will it be a good decision to use it for client-side? Or if I don't need in website, must I use only socket connection with TCP? And if I can, how my server URL will looks like?(`ip:port/` or `domain:port/` or `domain/`)

Comment: Yes, you can use HTTP requests without also writing HTML.

Comment: It is a bit hard to follow, perhaps https://ru.stackoverflow.com is a better fit for you. You have to check this, because I don't know any Russian ;-)

Comment: @Marged Is my English so bad? :(

Comment: My impression was that you have combined several questions in one post and that it might be easier to ask them in your native language. At least this is what I do when I have the choice between English and German ;-)

Comment: @SLaks Thanks :) So, i will just have a URL of my server, and i will send requests from Java code? Right?

Comment: @Marged To be honest, i cant ask question on RU stackoverflow, because Android StackOverflow it's only English forum, i dont now why :)